# How to remap caps esc to caps lock key in Lubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vim, keyboard, remap

I started using vim and I would like to remap some keys. Does anybody know whats the easiest way to do this in Lubuntu.

Thanks

Comment: do you mean like <CAPS><ESC> to <CAPS>? or <CAPS> to <ESC>? 

what specific about Lubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key cannot be mapped inside Vim, as it doesn't produce a keycode on its own. You can reassign / swap a different key (like <kbd>Esc</kbd>) on the operating system level, as outlines in [Map caps lock to escape in XWindows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Map_caps_lock_to_escape_in_XWindows).